# Is it possible to store Clickonce application files in SQL server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickonce

I am publishing Windows form application using ClockOnce in ASP.net web application. I understood that when user click on publish button then the clickonce application will be downloaded. this option is unsecure as anyone who know the download URL can download. to add Authentication I am using httphandler as per David P Henry suggestion from codeproject everything is working fine. I would like to add more security to this approach instead of placing the clickOnce app file in Application Files folder in web app I would like to place these files in SQL Server. So my application should able to download these file from SQL Server and send it to user.

Is it possible in Clockonce?

If possible I would like to know the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Use a VirtualPathProvider to read the files from SQL instead of the file system.

As ClickOnce requests the files via http/https it is possible to intercept each request and pass your own version (in this case read from SQL instead of the server's file system).

Linked below is a simple project that shows how to utilise a custom VirtualPathProvider.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16848/Creating-Custom-Virtual-Path-Provider-in-ASP-Net-2

I would suggest converting the directory where the files should be stored to an application and adding the Global.asax to the root of the application.

Then add a handler mappings for *.deploy and *.manifest for the root directory so your VirtualPathProvider will run when each file is requested.

Within the overridden FileExists method (in your VirtualPathProvider) write some logic  to return if the file exists or not. You could put some authorisation here but I don't know if ClickOnce caches Http responses, as the server would return a 404 if this function returns false.

Within the Stream Open() in your VirtualFile return a MemoryStream read from your SQL server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you prompt response. i will update once i try thsi option.